# failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\imgfox\upload.php on line 26 you try upload no/..image.

Tags: php, html, css

**i got this error while i working in image share service and while i try upload image nothing happens and no image gets upload and please can you add on the code the code which make every image uploaded stored in a folder ? 
my service code :**

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>upload images</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   image:
   <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php 
// connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("meinimages") or die(mysql_error());

// file properties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($file))
    echo "please choose an image.";
else
{
 $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));  
 $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_size = getimagesize($image);

 if ($image_size==FALSE)
     echo "you try upload no/..image.";
else
 {
    if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
      echo "problem while upload $image.";
    else
    {
      $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
      echo "image is uploaded.<p />your image:<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
    }



 }

}
```

Comment: Also read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for how to use MySQL securely.

Comment: what code i should replace or change

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: the corrected code plz

Comment: @flask  Stack overflow is not here to write code for you.  It's a question and answer site to help us al learn as software developers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code ~

```
<input type="file" name="uploadsrc" />

<?php
move_uploaded_file("uploads/".$_FILES["uploadsrc"]["name"]);
?>
```

No need to shout out your question as everybody can see it!